# Using a model state key and reflection to get the value of a display annotation

Tags: vb.net, reflection

Is it possible, given a model state key of `answersToQuestions[0].answer` or `[0].SelectedWorkFunctionId`, to get the value of a display annotation using reflection?

It is easy to do if it's just a single field in an object, but when the model is composed of other models or is a list, using the model state key with reflection we cannot get the data annotations for the property.

```
For i = 0 To ModelState.Keys.Count - 1           
    Dim field = model.GetType().GetProperty(ModelState.Keys(i))
    If Not IsNothing(field) Then
        Dim obj As New ViewErrorObjectModel
        obj.HTML_Id = ModelState.Keys(i).Replace("[", "_").Replace("]", "_").Replace(".", "_")
        obj.LabelValue = field.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DisplayAttribute), False).Cast(Of DisplayAttribute)().SingleOrDefault().Name
        obj.ErrorMessages.Add((From m In ModelState.Values(i).Errors Select m.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault)
        errorObjectModelList.Add(obj)
    End If
Next
```